# Why would Visual Basic 2010 application fail to initialize after running for 2 years just fine

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, windows-xp

We are getting a application failed to initialize error 0xc000007b.  I looked around it seems to maybe be the .NET framework, I also read a possible virus.

Our application is Visual Basic .NET 2010, running on Windows XP, Windows Update is turned on.

What fixes the problem, seems to be temporary, is take my backup copy of the .exe and replace the .exe on the machine, it runs for a few hours.  Keep in mind I am 12 hours away or more from the machine, I remote to it using TeamViewer.

Will event viewer or something else give me a better idea of what happened? or more information about the error and it's cause?

I'm far from a Visual Basic guru, so I'm very puzzled as to why this application is throwing this error after running for approximately 2 years.

Can windows update cause this? Does .NET framework update itself automatically?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you could restore to a recent restore point?

Comment: Windows Update means NOTHING in Windows XP anymore. Windows XP has been **end of life** for over a year now, meaning there are no longer **any** new updates, not even critical security updates. It's highly irresponsible to still be using XP.

Comment: Software does not wear out. Disk drives and cooling fans wear.  File corruption is the most logical explanation, when it strikes the header of a EXE or DLL file then Windows can generate this "invalid image format" exception.  Behaves like this as well, you can overwrite the file and re-magnetize the disk platter.  Works for a while, then the bits fall over again.  About 70 bucks and a few hours solves your problem, best to not have to do it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if your program was not recompiled, I'd doubt it's the program itself, but if you have the source code you can try running it through the debugger to see what's going on, and where. Personally I'd try just reimaging your xp system and seeing if that fixes the issue.

Also, isn't xp out of support? I suppose windows updates could affect it. I've seen updates cause older applications to break, so it is a possibility. You can look at the recent updates and roll them back.